# C# check for member of enum using input value

Tags: c#, events, delegates, enums

Let's say I have an `enum` called `eEventID` that contains 10 events, `mEvent1 - mEvent10` with `int` values 10001 - 10010 . I want to use an input value (e.g. 10007) to check if a member in the enum has the corresponding value. Once I find the event with the corresponding input value, I then take that event and register a method to it by hooking up a delegate (This is assuming I have all the necessary code). I just need to know if a member in the enum has a value that is the same as the input value, then register a new method to that event. How do I look for a certain event using only an input value? I'm guessing a `for-loop` or any other loop isn't my best bet.

**EDIT:** this is what I have so far...

```
public delegate void EventDel(int mEvtIdx);

public enum eVtEvtId
{
    Event1,
    Event2,
    Event3,
    Event4,
    Event5,
    Event6,
    Event7,
    Event8,
    Event9,
    Event10,

}

public void Subscribe(int mInVal)
{
    eVtEvtID mEventID;
    int mEventIndex = mInVal;

    if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(mEventID), mEventIndex))
    {
        mEventID += EventDelegate([insert method here])
    }

    else
    {
        // will warn the user that the event does
        // not yet exist in the enum
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you trying to dynamically attach an event handler to something or parse a string as an enum member?

Comment: the former, somewhat. I'm trying to get an event from an enum of events, then register methods to it.

Comment: Do either of the answers so far help you? If not, could you explain more about what you are trying to do that we have not addressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates how you would take a value (reading it from the console) map it to the numeric value corresponding to an enum member, locate the corresponding event (in this case on the `Program` class) and attach an event handler to it.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public enum Events
    {
        Event1 = 10001,
        Event2 = 10002,
        Event3 = 10003,
        Event4 = 10004,
        Event5 = 10005,
        Event6 = 10006,
        Event7 = 10007,
        Event8 = 10008,
        Event9 = 10009,
        Event10 = 10010
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static event Action Event1;
        public static event Action Event2;
        public static event Action Event3;
        public static event Action Event4;
        public static event Action Event5;
        public static event Action Event6;
        public static event Action Event7;
        public static event Action Event8;
        public static event Action Event9;
        public static event Action Event10;

        private static void OnEvent1()
        {
            if(Event1 != null)
            {
                Event1();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent2()
        {
            if (Event2 != null)
            {
                Event2();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent3()
        {
            if (Event3 != null)
            {
                Event3();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent4()
        {
            if (Event4 != null)
            {
                Event4();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent5()
        {
            if (Event5 != null)
            {
                Event5();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent6()
        {
            if (Event6 != null)
            {
                Event6();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent7()
        {
            if (Event7 != null)
            {
                Event7();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent8()
        {
            if (Event8 != null)
            {
                Event8();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent9()
        {
            if (Event9 != null)
            {
                Event9();
            }
        }

        private static void OnEvent10()
        {
            if (Event10 != null)
            {
                Event10();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();

                if(input == "q")
                {
                    return;
                }

                int value;

                if(int.TryParse(input, out value))
                {
                    var eventValue = (Events) value;
                    var eventName = Enum.GetName(typeof (Events), eventValue);

                    var matchingEvent = typeof(Program).GetEvent(eventName);

                    if (matchingEvent != null)
                    {
                        var action = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Event " + eventName + " has been handled"));
                        matchingEvent.AddEventHandler(null, action);
                    }

                }

                OnEvent1();
                OnEvent2();
                OnEvent3();
                OnEvent4();
                OnEvent5();
                OnEvent6();
                OnEvent7();
                OnEvent8();
                OnEvent9();
                OnEvent10();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not mapping the numeric value to the enum. I'm just using the numeric value to see if a member of the enum has the same value as the numeric value I have. I think that one part of the solution I need requires the `Enum.IsDefined` to be used, but that's as far as I can think of. I'm going to edit my question post, stay tuned.

Comment: @Anthony so the names of the members of the enum don't correspond to the names of the events you need to attach handlers to?

Comment: yes, they do not correspond to names of events. The members of the enum are events themselves. check my original post, I've added my code there just now.

Comment: @Anthony that, by definition, is not possible in .Net enums are constrained to have elements of numeric types

Comment: ......yeeaaaahh, I'm gonna have to brainstorm with my co-worker again. Damn, this is getting more and more complicated than I thought XD anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) method of your enum.

Basically its like this:

```
YourEnum enumVal;
if (Enum.TryParse(yourInputString, out enumVal)) {
   // use enumVal here
}
```

Comment: well, what you suggested didn't really help me, but what I read when I went to the link you provided DID help, so I still get to thank you. :D